# When I logged on to digital ocean (hosting) console access and typed enter, the console froze. How can I end this process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04

This is image of console access from **digital ocean**:

[image]

After logging in, I pressed enter and it started this configuration process and froze. 
(I deployed a rails4app and this is ubuntu 14.04 console).

Comment: are you login via ssh?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I was loggin in with root and password. I got an answer from DO that the console doesn't show any type for password field for security reasonm. I will close this question. Thanks for your help.